# Is this sentence correct? Usage of would have been and had

Tags: conditional-constructions

"I would have been prey for those cats had you not come, am I right?" Is this grammatically correct?

I dont understand that "had you not come" part. Is this some kind of conditional? Shouldn't there be something like "If you didnt come"?

Comment: You are right. "Had you not come" means "if you had not come."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is grammatical.

"Had you not come" is a rather literary alternative to "If you had not come". It can only be used (as far as I can think) with the auxiliaries "had", "should", "did" and "were" (which last betrays its origin as a form using the subjunctive: that is the only verb in Modern English which has a distinct subjunctive form).

The construction is perfectly understandable, but few people use it in speech.

Answer (score 0):

In formal situations, you can use had instead of if in counterfactual (conditional type 3) sentences in the structure Had + subject + past participle.

So your sentence, though formal, is correct grammatically.

Furthermore, in formal English, you can use "should" and "if were to" instead of if in conditional type 1 and conditional type 2 as follows:

Should you not come, I'll be prey for those cats.

If you were not to come, I would be prey for those cats.