# the explain of "had true teachers been" structure and meaning of "theta"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

the explain of "had true teachers been" structure and meaning of "theta"

Mr. Evans and his associates after the first disturbance, physical and
mental, caused by this spirit irruption, settled down to study what it
really meant. They came to the conclusion that the matter could be
divided into three phases. The first phase was the actual proving to the
observer that the thing was real. The second phase was one of
instruction, as even the humblest spirit can bring information as to his
own experience of after-death conditions. The third phase was called
the missionary phase and was the practical application. The Shakers
came to the unexpected conclusion that the Indians were there not to
teach but to be taught. They proselytized them, therefore, exactly as
they would have done in life. A similar experience has occurred since
then in very many Spiritualistic circles, where humble and lowly spirits
have come to be taught that which they should have learned in this
world **had true teachers been** available. One may well ask why the
higher spirits over there do not supply this want? The answer given to
the author upon one notable occasion was, "These people are very much
nearer to you than to us. You can reach **theta** where we fail."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this sentence correct? Usage of would have been and had](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110712/is-this-sentence-correct-usage-of-would-have-been-and-had) Briefly, ***had teachers been available*** is a "stylised, literary" alternative to the more natural ***IF teachers had been available***.

Comment: Presumably you've been reading the full preceding context, which I'm sure would have made clear exactly what ***reaching theta*** means here. I'm not gonna bother, but I'll guess ***theta*** is some "level of attainment" in a person's search for "spiritual meaning". Or perhaps it's just a misprint for ***them*** (i.e. - the Indians).

Comment: This question was closed without regard to the second question.  Theta is a term that is used in a variety of ways around divinity, spirituality and state of mind.  I believe, but can't be sure, it's referencing an altered state of divine consciousness.

Answer (score 0):

The construction, "had X been Y ..." means essentially, "X was not Y, but in an alternate universe where X **was** Y ..." For example,

> I would have ordered chicken soup if it had been on the menu.

or

> Had proper security been in place, the prisoner would still be in his cell.